# Merge Into Statement Erroring out at "Merge"

Tags: postgresql, sql-merge

I get the following error when trying to run a SQL "Merge Into" statement in Postgres:

> "ERROR: syntax error at or near "MERGE".

We are on Postgres 12.

Here is the SQL you can use to test.SET AUTOCOMMIT = ON;

```
/* Drop tables when done testing... */
-- DROP TABLE Stock;
-- DROP TABLE Buy;
-- DROP TABLE Sale;

/* Build Tables */

CREATE TABLE STOCK(ITEM_ID INT UNIQUE, BALANCE INT);
INSERT INTO STOCK VALUES (10, 2200);
INSERT INTO STOCK VALUES (20, 1900);


CREATE TABLE BUY(ITEM_ID INT, VOLUME INT);
INSERT INTO BUY VALUES(10, 1000);
INSERT INTO BUY VALUES(30, 300);


CREATE TABLE SALE(ITEM_ID INT, VOLUME INT);
INSERT INTO SALE VALUES (10, 2200);
INSERT INTO SALE VALUES (20, 1000);

/* Test out Merge Statement */

MERGE INTO Stock USING Buy ON Stock.item_id = Buy.item_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Stock.balance = Stock.balance + Buy.volume
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (Buy.item_id, Buy.volume);
;
```

Answer (score 2):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) Postgres has no merge statement.

You need to use `INSERT ON CONFLICT` instead

```
insert into stock (item_id, balance)
select item_id, volume
from Buy 
on conflict (item_id) do
  update SET stock.balance = stock.balance + excluded.volume;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I try the above statement, I get the following: INSERT INTO stock not successful
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
insert into stock (item_id, balance)select item_id, volume
from Buy
on conflict (item_id) do
update SET stock.balance = stock.balance + excluded.volum...

ERROR: relation "stock" does not exist
  Position: 13

insert into stock (item_id, balance)select item_id, volume
            ^
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0s

Comment: @mp75: "*relation "stock" does not exist*" - well then apparently your table has a different name